# JS, how to access to "this" in a replacer function in a call to String.prototype.replace()

Tags: javascript, this

I have this piece of code:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(text, pattern) {
    this.text = text;
    this.pattern = pattern;
  }

  run() {
    return this.text.replace(/(\d)/, this.replacer)
  }

  replacer(match, timeString, offset, string) {
    return this.pattern;
  }
}
```

It is a simplified example of my actual code.

When I run:

```
var v = new MyClass("text 1 2", "X");
v.run();
```

I see the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pattern')

How can access to `this` in this replacer function?

Comment: replace `this.replacer` with `this.replacer.bind(this)`

Comment: The `this.replacer` callback in the `.replace()` function is just a reference to the function at  the prototype of `MyClass`. However when it gets invoked as a callback from within `.replace()`, the `this` in it, namely the one at `this.pattern` represents the `String` object, which doesn't have a `pattern` property so `this.pattern` becomes `undefined`. So yes, you should `.bind()` it to `this` inside the constructor while the `this` still represents the instance to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the `this` value, or use an arrow function that calls `this.replacer` as the callback.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(text, pattern) {
    this.text = text;
    this.pattern = pattern;
  }

  run() {
    return this.text.replace(/(\d)/, this.replacer.bind(this));
    // or return this.text.replace(/(\d)/, (...args) => this.replacer(...args));
  }

  replacer(match, timeString, offset, string) {
    return this.pattern;
  }
}
var v = new MyClass("text 1 2", "X")
console.log(v.run());
```